# Getting proguard error on adding androidx biometric API ( "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1")

Tags: androidx, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am getting following error on building release apk after adding androidx biometric api "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1" in gradle file

Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
../release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
../release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
../release/values/values.xml:2853: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
../release/values/values.xml:2854: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

I am using below mentioned sdk / tools version
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28

I am able to build debug apk and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I created my app following the instructions given [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) and [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html). And I have no problems creating and running a release APK. Here is the proguard section of my Gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```